# In re module what does \.- do in [\w\.-]+?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I am writing a code to search for all the email addresses. I was wondering why I should write it as:
`'[\w \.-]+@[\w \.-]+'`
What does `\.-` do in `[\w\.-]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\w.-]` matches either a word character (`\w`), a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`). This is called a character class.